# Problems importing unreal mesh collisions

Tags: collision, unreal-engine4

I have an Unreal Engine 4 project. I have two sets of the same map, one unmerged and the other merged. THe merged map has the textures baked in. When I try to add a collision mesh in the baked level model everything works fine. When I try to add a collision mesh to the level broken down into several meshes, there isn't any option to add collision - in fact, half of the menu options aren't even there. I tried posting on the unreal forums without luck. I was hoping someone here might be able to help. Thanks - Ted

Answer (score 0):

When you select an object in UE4 it shows properties of that object. When you select several objects, it shows only the properties that the selected objects have in common. So my guess is that you trying to set up a collision for several objects of different type. Try setting it one by one.